# Datatables 1.10 enable pagination without recordsTotal

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I've recently moved from 1.9 to 1.10 and the pagination behavior is changed for ajax request.

In 1.9 I could not pass `iTotalDisplayRecords` or `iTotalRecords` and the pagination was still available as long as I was sending `sEcho` back.

This seems to no longer work in 1.10 and as long as I don't send `recordsTotal` value, pagination remains disabled.

I have some tables which contains 500k+ rows in db, counting them all to generate `recordsTotal` could be costly, especially if I need to do that on every page change.

I could build a caching mechanism which is also not the perfect solution as the first time I would still need to count these rows against my db, which could take some time and create slower experience.

Is there any other solution that I'm missing to keep the pagination available without counting all rows in db?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the pagination information message.

Example:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  "language": {
    "info": "Showing entries _START_ to _END_"
  }
});
```

See [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) for the related documentation.

You may also need to adjust this part of the message:

```
"infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)"
```

After doing this, you will no longer need to count total rows, because that info is never displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I've already disabled the info part and do not display the counts, however, the pagination buttons are still disabled if I don't send the `redordsTotal` value from my Ajax callback.

Comment: OK - understood. Assuming you have 500,000 database records, but you are only sending 100 records at a time to the client, what is the expected result for the page numbering (the section which shows "Previous  1  2  3  ... n  Next"). What value of "n" should be displayed, to represent the maximum page number?

Comment: Also, in case it helps - I tested a server-side DataTable with a `recordsTotal` value hard-coded to -1 (and then I hid the `"infoFiltered"` message). The pagination buttons are working OK (they are not deactivated). But you still have the issue of what you need the "max page number" to be. At some point I assume you will have to re-count the database records (perhaps in a separate process) to ensure a user can reach the correct "final page".

Comment: I've also tested with -1 value but the First/Prev/Next/Last buttons were disabled, only the page numbers were enabled. The only way I've figured out to overcome this is to make a hack to return something like: `count(items) > pageLength : count(items) * start + pageLength : count(items) * start` and hope for the best, but yeah, it's not exactly perfect... If there's no native resolve for this then I suppose I will need to create a caching mechanism to count total records and store the value.